# copying and pasting dynamic ranges on VBA, Error: Range of object_worksheet,

Tags: vba, excel

I have written/hashed together a programme for copying in a row of data for when the row meets a certain criteria (column A = "1") for all workbooks sitting in a test folder on my desktop; the programme worked initially but now pulls up an error here:

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 20)).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SummaryAccrual").Range("A" & lr2 + 1)
```

Once this is sorted, I'm also concerned that this method of copying and pasting will paste formulas and not values, is there an easy way to paste values?

Thanks for all your help, I super appreciate it!

**My Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub AccrualCombiner()

Dim Path As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim Wkb As Workbook
Dim cWkb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim answer As Integer
Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long, r As Long
Dim rc As Object

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

answer = MsgBox("Would you like to combine Accruals for current period?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Confirmation")

If answer = vbYes Then
    Set cWkb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    lr2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SummaryAccrual").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Path = "C:\Users\alexander.neale\Desktop\Test"
    FileName = Dir(Path & "\*.xls", vbNormal)

    Do Until FileName = ""

        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Path & "\" & FileName)
        For Each ws In Wkb.Worksheets
            For r = 14 To 60 Step 1
                If ws.Range("A" & r).Value = "1" Then
                    ws.Range(ws.Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 20)).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SummaryAccrual").Range("A" & lr2 + 1)
                    lr2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SummaryAccrual").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                End If
            Next r
        Next ws
        Wkb.Close False
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: try changing `ws.Range(ws.Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 20)).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SummaryAccrual").Range("A" & lr2 + 1)`  to : `ws.Range(ws.Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 20)).Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SummaryAccrual").Range("A" & lr2 + 1)`

Answer (score 1):

since you're interested in pasting values only, this should be faster:

```
Option Explicit

Sub AccrualCombiner()
    Dim Path As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim Wkb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim answer As Integer
    Dim r As Long

    answer = MsgBox("Would you like to combine Accruals for current period?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Confirmation")        
    If answer = vbYes Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

        Path = "C:\Users\alexander.neale\Desktop\Test"
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SummaryAccrual")
            FileName = Dir(Path & "\*.xls", vbNormal)
            Do Until FileName = ""
                Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Path & "\" & FileName)
                For Each ws In Wkb.Worksheets
                    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range(ws.Cells(14, 1), ws.Cells(60, 1)), "1") > 0 Then
                        For r = 14 To 60 Step 1
                            If ws.Range("A" & r).Value = "1" Then
                                .Cells(.Rows.COUNT, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, 20).Value = ws.Range(ws.Cells(r, 1), ws.Cells(r, 20)).Value
                            End If
                        Next r
                    End If
                Next ws
                Wkb.Close False
                FileName = Dir()
            Loop
        End With

        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 20)).Copy
```

the second `Cells` has no sheet specified so it will assume you mean the active sheet. If the active sheet is not `ws` then it will fail because a range can't span multiple sheets. Hence use

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(r, 1), ws.Cells(r, 20)).Copy
```

or

```
With ws
    .Range(.Cells(r, 1), .Cells(r, 20)).Copy ....
End With
```

---

edit: to paste only values, either just set the `.Value` property of the range, like user3598756 suggested:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SummaryAccrual").Range("A" & lr2 + 1).Resize(1, 20).Value = ws.Range(ws.Cells(r, 1), ws.Cells(r, 20)).Value
```

or use `PasteSpecial` with the `xlPasteValues` option:

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(r, 1), ws.Cells(r, 20)).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SummaryAccrual").Range("A" & lr2 + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

the first option usually is much faster.

Comment: Hi Arcade, You fixed the first problem, thanks!

Do you know how I would get the VBA to just paste the values rather than formulas? I tried the other two suggestions and couldn't get either to run. (one came up with an error, the other didn't copy anything)

Comment: @AlexNeale I edited my post. If user3598756's answer doesn't work for you, add a comment and describe the problem :)